# QGIS - Inaccurate field calculator

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, polygon, area, measurements

When I retrace a polygon using the measure area tool and get what I believe to be an accurate area measurement. However if I utilise the field calculator within the attribute table to calculate the area of all my polygons, I get a significantly different area measurement than the one above which I believe to be completely inaccurate.

What is the cause of this discrepancy?

Any ideas why the field calculator is throwing out the wrong figures ? I'm using a WGS84 projection - EPSG4326

Comment: What formula are you using to calculate the area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using [...] EPSG4326

there's your problem. This CRS is based on degree, so any distance/area calculations you do on this layer are done in degree, too.

Save your layer to a CRS based on meters, which fits your area of interest, then do the calculations.

Comment: Thanks Erik - Does OSGB1936 EPSG 4277 seems a sensible alternative ?

Comment: I have no idea, if it fits your AOI.